# use dotted world map in jqvmap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jqvmap

How can I put and modify jqvmap world map, with a dotted world map or changing the world map with a custom dotted map, I want to make it like as below picture

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jvectormap/2.0.2/jquery-jvectormap.css"  referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Dotted Jvectormap</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div id="world-map-markers" style="height: 300px"></div>
      <hr>
      <p>How can i make it like this map?</p>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a0/World_map_with_points.svg" alt="">
    </main>
  </body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jvectormap-next@3.1.1/jquery-jvectormap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ika.jvectormap@1.0.0/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js" ></script>
```

[image]